# DB2 trigger after update error

Tags: php, sql, db2

This is my first time using a trigger on my website using php. What I'm trying to achieve is when the condition and location field (located in inventory table) is updated, the trigger will insert a row to LOG table.

Here is the error shown when I chenged the condition and location field :

```
SQL0723N An error occurred in a triggered SQL statement in trigger "DB2ADMIN.CONDITI".        
Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-433", 
SQLSTATE "22001" and message tokens "Condition changed from bad ". SQLSTATE=09000 SQLCODE=-723
```

And here is my trigger code, I created the trigger using the data studio, and it succeeded :

**I'VE EDITED MY TRIGGER CODE AND LOG TABLE STRUCTURE, BUT STILL GENERATE THE SAME ERROR**

```
CREATE TRIGGER DB2ADMIN.CONDITION_LOG AFTER UPDATE OF CONDITION, LOCATION ON DB2ADMIN.INVENTORY 
REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL NOT SECURED 
INSERT INTO LOG VALUES ('',CURRENT TIMESTAMP, o.CONDITION, n.CONDITION, o.LOCATION, n.LOCATION);
```

Comment: i think you a bad query design..

Comment: The data is too long for the last column. Check the length of the last column and the data that you are trying to insert during the query.

Comment: @Meherzad the length for the last column is 1000 character, it should be enough

Comment: Then its ok...  Just went through the error code you provided found this reason.....   SQL0433 SQLCODE -433   SQLSTATE 22001

`Explanation: Significant digits truncated during CAST from numeric to character.`

Comment: Actually I wasn't casting from numeric to character, the condition and location is a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Heres a sample UPDATE TRIGGER**

this may not answer you question but i think it can help you to construct a better Trigger statement:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    TRIGGER `blog_after_update` AFTER UPDATE
    ON `blog`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.deleted THEN
            SET @changetype = 'DELETE';
        ELSE
            SET @changetype = 'EDIT';
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO audit (blog_id, changetype) VALUES (NEW.id, @changetype);
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Resource link([source](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-triggers/))